# validate Apache2.4 installation in windows 7 command prompt

Tags: apache, installation-package

I stalled Apache2.4.3 and PHP 5.4.11 on my desktop computer which runs Windows 7 professional. I would like to know what command shall I run in the command prompt to check if the Apache server has been properly installed.

1. On my C drive, Apache folder called **Apache24** and Php folder called php
2. I run a test.php file which has a phpinfo function in it. It showed PHP and Apache version information asApache/2.4.3 (Win32) PHP/5.4.11
3. the system showed the following message when I typed httpd.exe in the command prompt

   c:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe
   AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified do
   main name, using fe80::bcbd:7ef2:4d92:6a9. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally 
   to suppress this message

Please tell me what the above message means. Does it indicate the Apache is not installed properly?

1. I added 3 lines to the http.conf file 
   LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   PHPIniDir "c:/php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research online. Here is what I did to resolve my issue.

**install the Apache as a window service.**

- 1a. You should run the command prompt (DOS prompt) as an administrator, otherwise the window system will prompt an error message saying that your are not the administrator.
- 1b. To run command as an administrator, click on Window start up menu icon, find the command prompt icon, right click on it, then choose run as 'Administrator'
- 1c. in the Dos prompt, navigate to c:\apach24\bin\ folder, then type httpd -k install. This will install Apache as a window service.

I hope this helps. Thanks!